# Angular router links do not work until app is reloaded with browser's refresh button

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

In my Angular(v7) application, clicking on a router link does not load the relevant component although the URL is changed in the browsers address bar.

Once the page is reloaded clicking on the refresh button of the browser then the router links start to work as expected. I have confirmed the behaviour in both Google Chrome and IE.

Could you please show me what I'm doing wrong and where? I have shared the relevant parts of my code below.

**App module & router setup**

```
import {
  RouterModule,
  Routes
} from "@angular/router";
...

const appRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'bookings', 
    component: BookingsComponent, 
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]}, 
  {
    path: 'rates', 
    component: RatesComponent, 
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/bookings',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {
      enableTracing: false
    }),
    BrowserModule,
    ...
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Router Links in HTML template**

```
<a class="side-nav-link" routerLink="/rates" routerLinkActive="active">Rates</a>
<a class="side-nav-link" routerLink="/bookings" routerLinkActive="active">Bookings</a>
```

**Auth Guard, If it is relevant**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, private authService:AuthService) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    if (this.authService.loggedIn) {
      return true;
    }

    this.router.navigate( ['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: you have not defined route for `rates` and `bookings`

Comment: @ashishpal I have those routes in my actual code. I have added the same in the question's code snippet as well.

Comment: can you set `enableTracing` to true and add some logs?

Comment: don't use more than one router  outlet in same component.. use routiing children approach.. it will work..

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem. It was caused by having two router-outlets on a single page and switching between the two using an ngIf. This seems to be an Angular anti-pattern.

**Cause**

Here is an example of what I was doing:

File: app.component.html

```
<!-- Show toolbar and sidenav if logged in -->
<mat-toolbar *ngIf="isLoggedIn()">My App</mat-toolbar>
<mat-sidenav-container *ngIf="isLoggedIn()">
  <mat-sidenav>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="/page1">Page 1</a>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="/page2">Page 2</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>

<!-- Hide toolbar and sidenav if NOT logged in -->
<router-outlet *ngIf="isLoggedIn() === false"></router-outlet>
```

File: app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'page-1', component: Page1Component, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'page-2', component: Page2Component, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'page-1' }
];
```

I did this because I wanted two layouts: One for my main app content (with a toolbar and side-nav) and another for my login page (no toolbar and side-nav).

**Solution**

The correct way to do this is to create a two components, one for each of the layouts I wanted, and then use the routers children property. [Link to docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#child-route-configuration). For example:

File: app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

File: layouts/main-layout.component.html

```
<mat-toolbar>My App</mat-toolbar>
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="/page1">Page 1</a>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="/page2">Page 2</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

File: layouts/login-layout.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

File: app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login', component: LoginLayoutComponent, children: [
      { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '', component: MainLayoutComponent, children: [
      { path: 'page-1', component: Page1Component, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'page-2', component: Page2Component, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'page-1' }
    ]
  },
];
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thank you sir I had same issue and your solution worked.

Comment: Note: Just in case for anyone who was doing the same I was doing live reload and solution was not working until i recompiled with `ng serve` it worked.

Comment: @david-maccallum can you please help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65697694/condition-based-router-outlet-not-changing-its-content-on-url-change-in-app-comp

Answer (score -1):

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: 'login',
  component: LoginComponent
 },
 {
  path: 'rates',
  component: RatesComponent
 },
 {
  path: 'bookings',
  component: BookingsComponent
 },
 {
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/bookings',
  pathMatch: 'full',
  canActivate: [AuthGuard]
 },
 {
  path: '**',
  component: PageNotFoundComponent
 },
];
```

Your routes should be like this.

Comment: I actually have those routers in my actual code. Please check the edited question.

Comment: Is this happening on your local or deploying build to server?